# How can I split file in mac and then concat it Windows (e.g: using split and cat)?

Tags: windows, macos, split, terminal, cat

I have tried to split a file Mac using the command:

```sh
split -b 20mb myFile.zip
```

Then I get some files which start with x:

```
xaa xab
```

I have no problem to restore the file on Mac using the `cat` terminal command:

```
cat xaa xab > myFile.zip
```

But it fails to do the `cat` command on Windows.
Any solution that can work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following batch script will do what you need. Use it by `batchfile.bat x myFile.zip`, it loops through all files beginning with the specified prefix `x` and append them to a result file `myFile.zip` by using `type`:

```cmd
@echo off

set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<file_prefix^> ^<result_file^>
   goto eof
)

set "prefix=%~1"
set "resFile=%~2"

rem create new empty file in directory of batch file: %~dp0
break>"%resFile%"
rem loop through all output line of the dir command, unset delimns
rem so that space will not separate
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%prefix%*" /b /s /a-d') do (
   rem don't use the result file
   if not [%%a] == [%resFile%] (
      rem append the output to file
      type "%%a">>"%resFile%"
   )
)

:eof
```

Answer (score 3):

The batch file example above created a corrupted file.

This works fast and creates a usable zip file.

```
copy /b x* MacOS.zip
```

Comment: Note, if you run this in PowerShell, you have to run `cmd /c 'copy /b x* MacOS.zip'` so that it uses `copy` from `cmd`, rather than PowerShell's `copy` command.